Gradle Plugin - dependency on Java module also used in main project
I want that my gradle plugin depends on some common code that can be used inside the gradle plugin as well as inside a android library.
Is there a way to share plain java/kotlin code between a gradle plugin and an android library?
When I try to add a module to the gradle plugin I get "could ':...' could not be found in project" error... I tried different combinations of includeBuild and include but they don't solve the issue...
Example:
Gradle Plugin:
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
    `java-gradle-plugin`
    `maven-publish`
}

dependencies {
    // fails
    implementation(project(":Library:Plugin:Shared"))
    //implementation(project(":library:plugin:shared"))
}

Library Module:
plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
    id("kotlin-android")
    id("kotlin-parcelize")
    id("maven-publish")
}

android {

    // ...
}

dependencies {
    api(project(":Library:Plugin:Shared"))
}

Shared Module:
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm")
    `java-library`
    `maven-publish`
}

dependencies {
}

settings.gradle.kts:
pluginManagement {
    includeBuild(File("library/plugin/gradle"))
}

include(":Library:Plugin:Shared")
project(":Library:Plugin:Shared").projectDir = file("library/plugin/shared")

include(":Library:Plugin:Gradle")
project(":Library:Plugin:Gradle").projectDir = file("library/plugin/gradle")


EXAMPLE SETUP
1) root/gradle-plugin/build.gradle.kts
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl-base`
    `java-gradle-plugin`
    `maven-publish`
}

dependencies {
    //implementation(":gradle-shared")

    // following does not work inside a gradle plugin module...
    // it works in other modules though
    implementation(project(":Library:Plugin:Shared")) 
}

gradlePlugin {
    plugins {
        create("changelog-utils") {
            id = "changelog-utils"
            implementationClass = "<path>.ClassLoaderPlugin"
        }
    }
}

2) root/gradle-shared/build.gradle.kts
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl-base`
    `java-library`
    //`maven-publish`
}

3) root/settings.gradle.kts
// --------------
// Gradle Plugin
// --------------

includeBuild("gradle-plugin")

// --------------
// Shared Code (Plugin + Library)
// --------------

include(":MyLibrary:Plugin:Shared")
project(":MyLibrary:Plugin:Shared").projectDir = file("gradle-shared")


Use an included build
You need an included build to share code between a plugin and the application code of a project.
It's not clear to me where you are writing your plugin code, but the  logical place to put it is as a subproject of the included build, which I will describe below. Here are some step-by-step instructions.
Setting up the included build

Set up your included build project in a new folder under your main project folder. Call it, say, myIncludedBuild.

Give the included build its own settings.gradle.kts file in that folder. I suggest you write your plugin and the shared library in this project, so with that in mind, include both of them in what is going to be a multiproject project by writing the following in that file:
include("myPlugin", "myLibrary")



Setting up the plugin

Set up a folder for your plugin at myIncludedBuild/myPlugin. Give it a build.gradle.kts file and, assuming you are writing the plugin in Kotlin, apply the kotlin-dsl plugin1
plugins {
   `kotlin-dsl`
}


Continue this build.gradle.kts file to set out the details of your plugin in Java Gradle Plugin syntax. This gives that plugin the information it needs to package your plugin in the prescribed way for other projects to locate it.
gradlePlugin {
   plugins {
       create("myPlugin") {
           id = "myPluginId"
           implementationClass = "package.MyPlugin"
       }
   }
}


Put your plugin code in the file myIncludedBuild/myPlugin/src/kotlin/package/MyPlugin.kt (or whatever package suits you, reflecting it in the build file) in a class called MyPlugin implementing Plugin<Project>.

Setting up the library

For the library, set up a folder at myIncludedBuild/myLibrary and give it a build.gradle.kts file. In there apply the Java Library plugin and give the project a group.
plugins {
   `java-library`
}

group = "myIncludedBuildGroup"


Write your shared code in myIncludedBuild/myLibrary/src/main/java


Include the library in the plugin

To include the code of the library in the plugin code, add the following to the plugin's build.gradle.kts, importing it as a sister project:
dependencies {
    implementation(project(":myLibrary"))
}



Setting up the main project

Moving to your main project, include the build in your main settings.gradle.kts:
includeBuild("myIncludedBuild")


Now, the plugin will be available to be applied in the main project's build files:
plugins {
    id("myPluginId")
}


Also, the library will be available as a dependency to any project in your main build using its Maven co-ordinates:
dependencies {
    implementation("myIncludedBuildGroup:myLibrary")
}




1The Kotlin DSL plugin includes the Kotlin JVM plugin and the Java Gradle plugin; it puts the Kotlin Gradle DSL on the classpath; and it provides a convenient change to the Kotlin syntax to make regular Kotlin code similar to writing a Kotlin DSL build script, in that Gradle Action parameters are treated with their subject as receivers.

your answer did help me solve my issue - you did delete the most helping part though. To make my gradle plugin be able to use the shared java library, I needed the class path dependency - with this hint I could solve my problem.

One thing I could not solve was to move my gradle plugin and the shared project into a subfolder, because I could not get the classpath to work with a sub folder - any hints to this? Even setting the name of the includeBuild and trying to use this one did not work in the classpath...

I've been second guessing where your plugin code is all along (and I am still unsure). I think the best place for it is as part of your included build and I have described how to do that in a further edit.

I appreciate your help. I added a full setup to my question and added a comment in "1" - what you write as implementation(project(":myLibrary")) does not work for me. It works in "normal" projects, but I can't include a shared java module inside my gradle plugin module without using includeBuild or classpath as you initially suggested. Do you see the problem in my example?

You need to follow all the instructions. I know it's a lot, but almost all of it is essential to get this working. Both the plugin and the library need to be part of an included build. You need the new settings file, the folder structure I've described, etc etc

it was my fault, correct. Small changes to your suggestion and now it's working as expected. I simply completely overread that myIncludedBuild is a sub folder in which the shared library and the plugin is placed in. Thanks a lot

do you have a hint on why the gradle plugin is not published via maven? No matter if the gradle plugin is published automatically or if I publish it manually - it is not published by the roots publishToMavenLocal task and I'd like to publish it in jitpack. Seems like the includeBuild is the problem here and may need some additional setup?

The approach above does not involve publishing. It's self-contained and will automatically respond to any changes to plugin or library code without running any separate publishing tasks. You could have linked the projects by pure publishing but you'd have to re-publish for every change. You can certainly go on and publish any or all of the modules, normally using the maven-publish plugin. The included build link will not stop you doing so.

The problem is, that publishToMavenLocal from my root project does not publish my libraries included via includeBuild. Calling publishToMavenLocal from the plugin itself works, the task is there and is working, but somehow the root projects task does not know about it... The publishToMavenLocal from the root project does stop after calling the jar task for my plugin and does not call the maven related tasks.

Yes, that's the expected behaviour. If you want something different, more configuration is needed.

This is as a result of included builds being just that, separate builds, so they don't have the same degree of inter-linking that multi-project projects do.

as this question is answered I created a new question for the mavon compatible setup, I would appreciate your help there as well if you still have time to help me, thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78345653/structure-gradle-plugin-shared-code-libraries-in-a-maven-publishable-compati
