Structure gradle plugin + shared code + libraries in a maven publishable compatible way (sub project is a problem currently)
I want to combine following:

gradle plugin that can access a shared kotlin library
a shared kotlin library
libraries that can access the gradle plugin as well as the shared kotlin library

The base setup is the result of Gradle Plugin - dependency on Java module also used in main project which is based on a included build of a full sub project, sadly, this solution works locally only but does not solve the problem when I want to publish all modules via the maven plugin.
The setup looks like following currently:
Project Setup

settings.gradle.kts
gradle-plugin

settings.gradle.kts
plugin
shared


library

module1
module2
...



Description of setup

gradle-plugin: this is a sub project with its own settings.gradle.kts file

plugin... the gradle plugin
shared... the plain kotlin module that must be useable inside the plugin as well as inside all modules


module1... a library module, in my case an android library
module2... a second library module, in my case an android library

settings.gradle.kts in root:
includeBuild("gradle-plugin")
include("library/module1")
include("library/module2")

settings.gradle.kts of sub project inside gradle-plugin
include("plugin")
include("shared")

Question
I now want to change the structure and setup that all of that does not only work locally but can also simply published on maven. The current solution has the drawback, that all modules of the sub project are not published on maven because the publishToMavenLocal task of the root project does not know about the modules inside the sub project.
Can someone help me and explain, how I can adjust this setup so that I can simply pusblish it on maven as well?

Normal publishing
Every Gradle module is its own project, and in normal Java/Kotlin setup will produce its own JAR file as an outgoing artifact.
You can publish this JAR for each project by adding and configuring the Maven publish plugin (maven-publish) in each project, and then running the publishing tasks. So in your case that would include doing so in plugin, shared, module1 and module2.
In a Maven repository, each one of these projects would come with a pom.xml file (generated by the plugin) which tells a build tool what the dependencies of that project are, using Maven coordinates1. So I could, with access to your repo, start my own Gradle project, add module1 as a dependency, and then I would expect Gradle to find all the other dependencies in the repo, following the pom.xml.
Configuring the publishing tasks
If you are setting up a very similar publishing configuration across projects, you may find there is a lot of duplication. This is another use-case for another Gradle plugin. You can write your shared configuration in that and apply it to the projects that need such publishing configuration.
Fat JARs
You might not like that output because it spreads the program across too many different modules. If you want to change it then you either have to reconfigure your Gradle setup to use fewer modules, or you will need to move the compiled Java .class files and any resources around to reduce the number of artifacts/JARs. You can do this by constructing so-called fat JARs, and Gradle have written a bit of a guide on that.
Running the publishing tasks
I wasn't sure if you were also querying how to run the publishing tasks.
When you run a task like publishToMavenLocal from the root project, it will run all tasks in all subprojects with that name (docs). In your case, that would publish module1 and module2, assuming you've set up the publishing in those projects.
It wouldn't publish plugin and shared, since those are in an included build. For that, you can instead separately run ./gradlew :gradle-plugin:publishToMavenLocal to run the publishing tasks in that, separate, multi-project project.
If running those two separate tasks is still too fiddly, you can link them all together since it is possible to call included build tasks from a main project (docs).

1This picks up from the group, name and version properties of each subproject, so make sure these are configured to your liking.

what I need is the very last point: everything must be linked by the main publishToMavenLocal. I publish my library on jitpack.io and this service detects only what is listet by the main publishToMavenLocal task. Everything is published now (with dependencies) but the problem is, that everything is published in the root. This results that the plugin is working after release, but module1/2 are not because they do include the shared code via api("gradle-plugin:shared") but maven releases the library under shared directly. so the releases modules to not find their dependency shared

the easiest solution is to release the gradle-plugin separately, but is that really necessary to get this working?

I think the "let's run it all as one task" is a red herring. If you got that working, it would only be the same as running the tasks separately, and in any case you can also change the jitpack config. You'd still end up with multiple published libraries. Ultimately you have three choices: (1) publish all the libraries separately, (2) re-juggle the packaging of the code using fat JARs or similar prior to publishing or (3) go back to a sub-optimal Gradle setup and live with code duplication. (1) and (2) are described above.

I want everything being published separately - I could solve the problem by moving the shared code up to the main project and and then including it in the libraries as project and inside the plugin as ..\shared - this way, everything works after publishing. Of course the shared code is duplicated in the plugin library, but that's ok, because the plugin is only used in the project locally and is not part of any resulting app.
